# Ruby factorial code runs too slow

Tags: ruby, performance, algorithm, combinations

I am working on [this hackerrank challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/handshake/copy-from/10387415).

I wanted to try the problem with ruby, and this is the code that I wrote:

```
gets.to_i.times do
    num_people = gets.to_i
    num_people_factorial = (1..num_people).inject(:*) || 1
    numerator = num_people_factorial
    if num_people > 2
        denominator = 2*((1..num_people - 2).inject(:*) || 1)
    elsif num_people == 2
        denominator = 2
    else
        denominator = 10000    
    end
    puts numerator / denominator
end
```

The problem is, when I run it on my computer, I get the right answer, but when I run it through Hackerrank's system, the test cases time out - they don't execute quickly enough to be graded.

How can I optimize this code?

EDIT: When I submit this code, I see this result:

[image]

Comment: I went to the site and copy-pasted your coding exactly and ran the coding. It worked perfectly with their test cases.

Comment: Did you just "run" or "submit" the code? Because I've submitted this code three times now, only passes three out of 10 test cases

Comment: Didn't want to submit your coding to be honest. You could just use something like this though:
    tot = 1; 1.step(i,1).to_a.each { |x| tot=tot*x }; puts tot

Comment: Obviously add his "constraints" and rules to it, but that should be all the work itself

Comment: I don't understand. Is that more efficient? I am not using a variable `i`. Could you add this as an answer that is runnable?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about refactoring and code review of working code. [codereview.se] is a better fit than [so].

Comment: Sorry, I'll cross post it. My thinking was that it has to do with why `(1..num_people).inject(:*)` is not efficient, and what should be used when taking factorials in ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be vigilant to avoid the dreaded ["XY" question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)! From the title you've assumed you need to compute a factorial.  Why?  You are over-thinking.  The question is if there are N people in the room, how many handshakes will take place. Each of N people shakes hands with (N-1) people, but that counts each handshake twice, so the answer is:

```
N*(N-1)/2
```

I can't be sure, but I expect this will pass the benchmark test.

As you can quickly and easily compute this number, even without a computer, calculator or even paper and pencil, you now have another way to impress other guests at dinner parties.